# Mongoose, check if value exists in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with: **I want to use the** `$in` **operator**

```
Person = {
 name: String,
 members: [ {id: String, email: String}... {}]
}
```

I use this so far:

```
Person.find({members: {"$in": [id1]}})
```

But I already know the flaw: If the array of members was like `Members: [id1, id2, ... id3]` that method would work. But it is an array of objects. So how do I get around it?

Answer (score 42):

`$elemMatch` can be used with [Arrays of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents):

In your case you could try:

```
Person.find({ 
   members: { 
      $elemMatch: { id: id1 } 
   }
});
```

But since it is a [Single Query Condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition):

```
Person.find({ 
   "members.id": id1
});
```

Would do the trick.

Comment: best answer imo.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `members.id` as field in your query to match your subdocument `id`s :

```
Person.find({ "members.id": { "$in": ["id1"] } })
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use elem match in the following way:

```
db.collection.find({
  arrayfield: {
    $elemMatch: {
      id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123461")
    }
  }
})
```

The same can be done in mongoose in the following ways:

```
query.elemMatch('arrayfield', { id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123461") })
```

.

```
query.where('arrayfield').elemMatch({ id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123461") })
```

.

```
query.elemMatch('arrayfield', function (elem) {
  elem.where('id').equals(ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123461"));
})
```

.

```
query.where('arrayfield').elemMatch(function (elem) {
  elem.where({ id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123461") });
})
```

I have used this example collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123451"),
    "arrayfield": [
      {
        id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123461"),
        name: "David"
      },
      {
        id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123462"),
        name: "Brown"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123452"),
    "arrayfield": [
      {
        id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123471"),
        name: "Maple"
      },
      {
        id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123472"),
        name: "Green"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123453"),
    "arrayfield": [
      {
        id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123461"),
        name: "David"
      },
      {
        id: ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123482"),
        name: "Lacey"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Want to try live? Try it on mongo playground with this link
https://mongoplayground.net/p/H3fdmp9HkQv

Comment: i wanna match multiple ids like 5eaaeedd00101108e1123461, 5eaaeedd00101108e1123482 to find devid and lacey